# Could the universe be a bubble in a larger mass?

Tags: cosmology

I was reading [this article](http://www.cnn.com/2015/11/11/opinions/lincoln-einstein-dark-energy/)  which explains that Einstein originally thought about incorporating dark energy into relativity.  It explains that dark energy is the thing that keeps pushing the universe apart and explains why its expansion is not slowing down.

I came up with a hypothesis and I wonder if it's plausible..

What if the universe is not being pushed apart but rather pulled apart from all directions?  Could this happen in a universe where empty space was the exception rather than the norm?  In this mass filled universe, some event tantamount to a universe-scaled black hole forms leaving a bubble of rare empty space around it and then explodes in a big bang.  Now the surrounding mass explains the accelerating expansion.

Comment: you have 2 anwsers to the same question here : [Is the observable universe enclosed by an infinitely dense shell?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/is-the-observable-universe-enclosed-by-an-infinitely-dense-shell)

Comment: To be more precise... you didn't come up with a theory but, at most, with a hypothesis. Now you have to suggest empirical ways to test and distinguish it from other such hypotheses and then you have to carry out those tests. If they are in favor of your hypothesis, it may, one day, become a theory or at least part of one.

Comment: i figured i wasn't the first person to think of it... will change theory to hypothesis